# Typo3 cal (calendar Base) extension update error

Tags: typo3

have just updated typo3 calendar base extension and suddenly the typo3 backend and frontend displays disappeared and all i see is a blank display. This is the exact error I'm getting

> ... PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/typo3conf/ext/cal/res/class.tx_cal_isCalNotAllowedToBeCached.php' (include_path='/var/www/html/typo3/contrib/pear/:.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/typo3temp/Cache/Code/cache_core/ext_localconf_6068a12d352941d6e5ee7dd31447d561068faea3.php on line 3617....

how do I clear this to get my typo3 back? I'm using typo3 6.2.12, my efforts of even deleting the cal extension don't work!

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Open the install tool and clear all caches in the "Important Actions" section. It seems there is some old code from before the update still cached. Note the path of the file doing the include, it is in `typo3temp/Cache/Code/`.

Comment: Hi Jost thanks for your help but like I said I'm not able to log into either backend or the frontend. they both give me a blank display. I bet working from the affected files would be a good start and there is where I'm stack!!

Comment: Try this: 1) try to open the install tool directly (open the URL `/typo3/install`), and/or 2) Clear the directory `/typo3temp`, the stuff in there will be regenerated.

Comment: Thanks Jost, going by the install tool option worked for me. I feel a little stupid though that that never crossed my mind.